# Docker timeout error mssql17 connection on M1 arm64 architecture

Tags: sql-server, docker, apple-m1, arm64

Could you please help me resolve this issue:

I must to say that everything is working fine on Windows amd64 architecture
But when I tried to start docker-compose on arm64 M1 it went wrong and makes the error

So I have these 2 Dockerfiles

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-buster as builder

WORKDIR ...

COPY ...

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git g++ libgirepository1.0-dev unixodbc unixodbc-dev pkg-config libcairo2-dev gcc python3-dev

RUN pip install virtualenv &&\
    python -m venv antenv

RUN . antenv/bin/activate &&\
    python -m ensurepip --upgrade &&\
    pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    pip install wheel gobject PyGObject &&\
    pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR ...

COPY --from=builder ...

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl gnupg -y
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - &&\
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools -y &&\
    apt-get install -y unixodbc python3-gi gir1.2-secret-1 alembic &&\
    . antenv/bin/activate && pip install gunicorn &&\
    mkdir -p /opt/antenv/nltk_data

EXPOSE 5000

CMD . antenv/bin/activate && alembic -x data=true upgrade head && gunicorn wsgi:app -w 1 --worker-class eventlet --threads 2 --forwarded-allow-ips=* -b 0.0.0.0:5000
```

and DataBase:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

WORKDIR /opt/mssql/

# Bundle config source
COPY ./*.sh /opt/mssql/bin/

RUN chmod +x /opt/mssql/bin/*.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["tail -f /dev/null"]
```

As you can see **I mentioned everywhere that it is linux/amd64 platform**

DataBase is upping good and I don`t get eerors
But when I up Backend, It as if does not see database and I get timeout error

```
backend  | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
backend  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: One is curious as to why you're using the Ubuntu 20.04 package repo with `https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list`. If you `docker run -it --rm python:3.9-buster cat /etc/os-release` you can see that it reports as `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` instead. If you consult [Linux Software Repository for Microsoft Products](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software) you'll see that Debian 10 should be pulling from the `https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod` repo.

Comment: Amd64 doesn’t run on ARM / M1. Docker may not have returned errors but that doesn’t necessarily mean SQL Server is actually running. Did you verify with docker ps? Did you check SQL Server’s error log to make sure it didn’t fail silently? Try Azure SQL Edge. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7099/testing-sql-server-edge-and-docker-on-the-latest-macbooks/